# BitLocker and Active Directory

Tags: security, encryption, active-directory, bitlocker

I routinely bring in my encrypted file drive to work, but the IT department seems rather incompetent here. The security policies are very lax, and I'm paranoid about the domain controller being hacked into. If this were to happen, and the domain controller were to be hacked, could an attacker freely access my drive?

I brought this question here and not ServerFault/Information Security because this involves my personal drive. So, please don't flag this as off-topic.

Comment: They would still need the passphrase in order to mount the drive, even if they gained access to your user profile, you are over thinking this.

Comment: I'm not. I'm assuming the worst about Active Directory. The drive is already mounted on the computer.

Comment: Unless you have your profile to automatically mount the drive, any attempt to access the drive, would result in a prompt for the passphrase.  Of course access to just the domain controller wouldn't necessarily provided access to your workstation.

Comment: What about when a drive is encrypted FROM a domain computer and the recovery hash is stored in AD so that a domain admin can be a recovery agent?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote? If you're going to downvote, comment so that the question can be improved. Totally unfair.

Comment: @BigChris - That seems outside of the scope of this question.  If that is within the scope of the question, the question should be updated, to reflect that fact.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, if the Bitlocker drive is configured to allow access to anyone logged in via your domain account to unlock it without additional passphrases, etc., then yes, a hacker who has successfully hacked the company DC could access it.

If they hacked the DC, theoretically they could grab the security hive/hash table which contains all the domain account passwords, [crack the hashes to get your password](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/How-Cracked-Windows-Password-Part2.html), log into your computer/account as you, and access the drive, all without you knowing it.

Reality:

In general DC's are very hard to crack, especially if there's even a basic firewall in the way.  The IT staff would have to be completely clueless not to at least have that kind of protection against the Internet.

Aside from that, if you don't trust the IT staff, don't hook your drive to their network.

Comment: The drive is accessible by entry of a password, and I'm worried a domain controller would be able to discreetly pull files from it while it's plugged in and mounted to the computer. I'm even worried about file names being able to be read, as this could make me a target. Not only that, Im paranoid about privacy invasions by the IT department. Sure I could make a complaint, but this would be after the fact. I'm not a standard blue-collar worker. For this reason as well, you can't just suggest I not bring it in since you have no context.

Comment: In the context you have provided thus far, you should not bring the drive in if you don't trust the network.  Anyhow your question wasn't about avoiding it, is was 'is it possible', and I gave you a/the scenario where it would be.   While the drive is mounted, decrypted and hooked to a domain computer there's NOTHING you can do to stop a domain admin account (user, service, system or otherwise) from accessing it, and I have trouble believing anyone would hack into a DC and not give themselves Domain Admin access. :)

Comment: If they rely on manually provided credentials to decrypt (and are not actively unlocked) then you're pretty safe.